# print cyrillic string from json php

Tags: php, json, cyrillic

I receive json answer from another script. Next I used $json = json_decode($json) and die(json['message']) for show specific string, and this value contains Cyrillic data.

Function mb_detect_encoding() shows that string in UTF-8.

Ok, I use  charset="utf-8" in html file, but 
I see this output "РџРѕР»СЊР·РѕРІР°С‚РµР»СЊ СЃ СЌС‚РёРј Р°РґСЂРµСЃРѕРј СЌР»РµРєС‚СЂРѕРЅРЅРѕР№ РїРѕС‡С‚С‹ СѓР¶Рµ СЃСѓС‰РµСЃС‚РІСѓРµС‚" in my browser.

I used mb_convert_encoding(json['message'], 'UTF-8'), without any effect/

Only var_dump($json) shows me decoded string.

Maybe I wrong to access data in json?

Comment: This is UTF-8 text with http header `Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mb_convert_encoding(json['message'], "utf-8", "windows-1251");` to properly convert string.

Comment: I did it. It doesn't work.I got this "Р СџР С•Р В»РЎРЉР В·Р С•Р Р†Р В°РЎвЂљР ВµР В»РЎРЉ РЎРѓ РЎРЊРЎвЂљР С‘Р С Р В°Р Т‘РЎР‚Р ВµРЎРѓР С•Р С РЎРЊР В»Р ВµР С”РЎвЂљРЎР‚Р С•Р Р…Р Р…Р С•Р в„– Р С—Р С•РЎвЂЎРЎвЂљРЎвЂ№ РЎС“Р В¶Р Вµ РЎРѓРЎС“РЎвЂ°Р ВµРЎРѓРЎвЂљР Р†РЎС“Р ВµРЎвЂљ"